# What is the preferred way to store coordinates (x,y) in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, relational-database

I am creating a service in which the users are able to store some coordinates. (int x, int y).

These coordinates are part of another object, let's say `Person`:

```
class Person {
    String name;
    Coordinates coordinates;
}

class Coordinates {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

The `Coordinates` object is required only with some upper context - in this example it is `Person`, but sometimes it could be `Place` or `Company`. The `Coordinates` object alone is completely useless.

The question is: how to store such data in relational database. Should I create a relation with generated keys, or maybe store it as a comma-separated String inside upper object?

What is a good, recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is: how to store such data in relational database. Should
>   I create a relation with generated keys, or maybe store it as a
>   comma-separated String inside upper object?

**In the DBMS side,** splitting a table in two parts may be interesting when you can define two concepts that may be manipulated in an independent way.
It is not your case as you explain that the coordinates entity alone is completely useless.

It may also be interesting to split when two concepts mix a lot of properties that have not a relation direct between them and you don't want to couple them in a same table as it would be undesirable in terms of reading and maintainability.
It is still not the case as the coordinates have only two properties.
For example for a Person-Address (one to one) relation, it would make more sense.

So, introducing a specific table for the coordinates would probably bring more drawbacks than advantages.

**Now in the Java object side**, having a `Coordinates` field in the Person class makes sense as you could manipulate it as an object and not only as a set of individual properties.

The Embeddable and Embedded mechanisms of JPA allow to define an entity as a part of another entity while mappping all of them to a single physical table.

Specify the entity to include as an Embeddable entity and in the entity that includes it specify the field as an Embedded entity.

```
@Embeddable
class Coordinates{
    int x;
    int y;
}

@Entity
class Person{
    String name;
    @Embedded
    Coordinates coordinates;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Coordinates object alone is completely useless.

From this line you should start thinking of imbeddable,also I do not see how an object could be reused for more than a place since a slight difference in the coordenation will produce a new instance,